# Is there a way to make /proc like status files from a user process?

Tags: linux, file-io, proc

I'd like to know if there is a way to create a /proc like file in a user mode application.

Basically, I'd like to have a set of files that are available for reading, that when read invoke a function in user space, similarly to how the kernel /proc files are managed.

Is it possible to do something like use mknod to make a file, then place its fd in a epoll loop, and when ready write the computed data to it?

Thanks in advance!

-bms

Comment: Yes, this is possible with a little kernel-mode help from [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/).